# Spring data jap multi tables' columns with join

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, user_info and user_password. I wanna display typeName directly when show the userInfo detail information, but I don't want to config the relationship(OneToMany or ManyToOne) between this two entity.But it doesn't work,who can help me ?

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class UserInfo {// user_info
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Byte gender;
    private String thirdPartId;
    private Integer age;
    private String telphone;
    private String registerMode;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class UserPassword {//user_password

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String encryptPassword;
    private Integer userId;


}


/** 
 * This is wish result entity
 * @author Mason
 * @version v1.0
 * @since 2019/1/16
 */
@Data
public class UserInfoPassword {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Byte gender;
    private String thirdPartId;
    private Integer age;
    private String telphone;
    private String registerMode;
    private String encryptPassword;
}

 @Query(value = "SELECT u.id,u.name,u.gender,u.third_part_id,u.age,u.telphone,u.register_mode,p.encrypt_password FROM user_info u " +
            "LEFT JOIN user_password p ON  u.id=p.user_id ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserInfoPassword > queryAll();
```

> this return type UserInfoPassword will occur exception:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.mason.sell.repository.model.UserInfoPassword]

if i change the return Object,and do that:

```
 List<Object> userInfoPasswords = userInfoRepository.queryAll();
        for (Object o : userInfoPasswords) {
            UserInfoPassword uip = (UserInfoPassword) o;
            System.out.println(uip);
        }
```

then will occur this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.mason.sell.repository.model.UserInfoPassword

who have great ways to do multi table join query???

Answer (score 0):

It would return an object array as you have not provided any mapping.

Try this:-

```
List<Object[]> userInfoPasswords = userInfoRepository.queryAll();
for (Object o[] : userInfoPasswords) {
    System.out.println("id: " + o[0]); // or call the setter of new UserInfoPassword
    System.out.println("name: " + o[1]);
    // ... and so on
}
```